# Kernel Development : Hooking Execve And Printing char *const argv[]

Tags: c, unix, linux-kernel, hook, rootkit

I am trying to HookExecve and print arguments. I can print the filename just fine. How can I print the arguments of **char *const argv[]** in Kernel mode ? I need to e able to get the amount of them and also be able to print them.

So if I run ls -lah . I should see in argv ["ls", "-lah"] ; I can do this in user space, but All attempts to copy the information from user space to Kernel space seems to lead to crash.

```
    char CharBuffer [255] = {'\0'};
    char Argz       [255] = {'\0'};

    asmlinkage int (*origional_execve)(const char *filename, char *const argv[], char *const envp[]);
    asmlinkage int HookExecve(const char *filename, char *const argv[], char *const envp[]) {
       unsigned int len     = sizeof(CharBuffer) / sizeof(CharBuffer[0]);
       unsigned int Argzlen = sizeof(Argz)       / sizeof(Argz[0]);

        copy_from_user(&CharBuffer , filename , len );
        //copy_from_user(Argz , argv[0] , sizeof(argv[0]) );     
        //strncpy_from_user(Argz, argv[0], len ); // Might break stuff
        printk( KERN_INFO "Executable Name %s \n", CharBuffer  );
        memset(CharBuffer, 0 , len);

      return (*origional_execve)(filename, argv, envp);
    }
```

Comment: Please post what you expect your code to do.

Comment: I am not sure if I was clear , but I am hooking the execve call in linux. I just want to print the argv strings.

Answer (score 0):

> sizeof(CharBuffer) / sizeof(CharBuffer[0])

**No**. This is just `sizeof(char*)/sizeof(char)`.

> sizeof(Argz)       / sizeof(Argz[0])

**No**. This is just equal to `sizeof(char**)/sizeof(char*)`.

`sizeof` does *not* get you the count of elements in an array. `sizeof` returns the size of the underlying type.

To get length of a string (ie. count of characters until a terminating zero character is found) use `strlen`. `strlen` returns `size_t` type, as does `sizeof`.

`argv` array ends with a [sentinel value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value) `NULL`. To print the content of a `char **argv` array, iterate until you find a null:

```
for (char *i = argv; *i != NULL; ++i) {
    printf("%s\n", *i);
}
```

or:

```
for (size_t i = 0; argv[i] != NULL; ++i) {
    printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
}
```

> char CharBuffer [255] = {'\0'};
>   &CharBuffer

Although equal to the value, `&CharBuffer` is not `char*` type. `&CharBuffer` has the type `char (*)[255]` - it's a pointer to an array of 255 characters. Enable your compiler warnings and solve them - in kernel do not make mistakes. Just use `CharBuffer` which is converted to `char*` type in `strcpy`-likeish functions.

You seem to kind-of to want:

```
char char_buffer[255] = {0};
// Note: Do not name variables similar, especially globals.
// The argc <-> argz <-> argv differ only in one char.
// and 2d array to hold arguments strings
char argz[255][255] = {0};
// the count of arguments
size_t argc = 0;

asmlinkage int (*origional_execve)(const char *filename, char *const argv[], char *const envp[]);
asmlinkage int HookExecve(const char *filename, char *const argv[], char *const envp[]) {

    if (strlen_user(filename) + 1 > sizeof(char_buffer)) {
         // TODO: no memory for filename
         return -1;
    }
    copy_from_user(char_buffer, filename, strlen_user(filename) + 1);

    size_t i = 0;
    for (i = 0; argv[i] != 0; ++i) {

         // note: argz has type `char (*)[255][255]`
         // so: sizeof(argz) = 255 * 255 * sizeof(char)
         // *argz has type `char (*)[255]`
         // so: sizeof(*argz) = 255 * 255 * sizeof(char)
         // so: sizeof(argz)/sizeof(*argz) = 255
         // This would NOT work if `argz` would be a `char**`...
         // if (i > sizeof(argz)/sizeof(*argz)) {
         // but there is ARRAY_SIZE macro that does the same
         if (i > ARRAY_SIZE(argz)) {
              // TODO: not enough indexes
              return -1;
         }

         // sizeof(argz[i]) = sizeof(char(*)[255]) = 
         //                 = 255 * sizeof(char) = 255
         if (strlen_user(argv[i]) + 1 > sizeof(argz[i])) {
              // TODO: no memory to copy
              return -1;
         }
         copy_from_user(argz[i], argv[i], strlen_user(argv[i]) + 1);
    }
    argc = i;

    printk( KERN_INFO "Executable Name %s \n", char_buffer);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < argc; ++i) {
        printk( KERN_INFO "arg[i] = %s\n", argz[i]);            
    }

    return (*origional_execve)(filename, argv, envp);
}
```

I DID NOT TEST THE CODE and most probably it contains many errors. It would be also better to handle errors better and to just use dynamic allocation and handle allocation errors.

Comment: Strlen for some reason leads to crash when using it on a parameter .I will need to figure out how to work with this strict kernel.

Comment: Hello I think the Link is dead ?

Comment: Do `strlen_user` for buffers from users.

Comment: Here is the link you wanted I think to post.  
https://www.fsl.cs.sunysb.edu/kernel-api/re250.html

Answer (score 0):

I am currently implementing a simple LSM (not sure if you want this because of the rootkit tag) which hooks `execve()` via the `bprm_check_security()` hook to check for signatures.

To get an idea how to access strings of `argv[]` and `envp[]` I used TOMOYO Linux as exactly the starting point I needed, as I couldn't do it reliably by just poking around memory in `struct linux_binprm`.
The argument count `argc` is always available via `bprm->argc` but the strings itself are not easily accessible.

This simplified example prints parameters and the environment variables if a bash script is directly executed via bash.

```
static int mylsm_bprm_check_security (struct linux_binprm *bprm){
    
    struct tomoyo_page_dump dump = { };

    if (strstr(bprm->filename, "bash")){ 
        printk(KERN_EMERG "<mylsm> %s\n", tomoyo_print_bprm(bprm, &dump));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Which gets us this very nicely formatted output:

```
target_board:~# echo "echo hacked" > hacked.sh
target_board:~# bash hacked.sh
[   84.033006] <mylsm> argv[]={ "bash" "hacked.sh" } envp[]={ "BOARD=redacted" 
"ARCH=x86_64" "TARGET_SYS=redacted" "TZ=Universal" "HUSHLOGIN=FALSE" "USER=root" 
"TARGET_ARCH=x86_64" "PWD=/root" 
"HOME=/root" "HOST=redacted" "SHELL=/bin/sh" "TERM=vt100" "SHLVL=0" "LOGNAME=root" 
"PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin" "HISTFILESIZE=10" }
hacked
```

To see how this works you need a few things from TOMOYO Linux itself:

To be able to save the dumped memory pages:

- `struct tomoyo_page_dump` - https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/security/tomoyo/common.h?h=v5.15.24#n577

To dump the memory page containing the desired strings into the structure above:

- `bool tomoyo_dump_page(struct linux_binprm *bprm, unsigned long pos, struct tomoyo_page_dump *dump)` -
  https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/security/tomoyo/domain.c?h=v5.15.24#n896

This does the actual magic by looping through memory and returning us some strings:

- `static char *tomoyo_print_bprm(struct linux_binprm *bprm, struct tomoyo_page_dump *dump)` -
  https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/security/tomoyo/audit.c?h=v5.15.24#n22

After putting everything together in your own LSM you could do it with those hooks or derive your own code from it.